# How to know the contract address is multisig or not

Tags: etherscan, gnosis-safe

[image]

like the image above, how can etherscan know the CA is Safe Multisig Contract?

Is there any way to detect the contract address whether it is safe multisig or not?

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan turns blockchain data into their own relational database. As such, they have their own data libraries to match contract bytecode to known contracts. I can reasonably assume that when they match a new contract's bytecode to the known `GnosisSafeProxy` bytecode, they auto-assign that tag.

There are two ways you could reasonably do this:

One is to essentially copy what Etherscan does -- retrieve and store the bytecode ([`eth_getCode`](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getcode)) of a known Gnosis Proxy contract (your Safe address is a Proxy), then `eth_getCode` of any arbitrary address and compare. If they match, you are certain to have a `GnosisSafeProxy` of that specific version.

Alternatively, you could query the Safe address for the method `masterCopy()(address)` using any web3 library. None of the other methods on the implementation contract are really as unique.

Note that this isn't foolproof; any contract is free to define a method called `masterCopy`, but the chances of that are much lower than any of the other contract methods.